# What to use before "for over" the past six months?

Tags: past-perfect, exam-questions

I has a test a few days ago and one of the questions was weird to me and I can't explain how.

The question:

> My boyfriend, Tom, ______ twenty pounds for over the past six months.

The given answer was "has lost" but I found it weird because there was a "for", can anyone tell me if I'm correct or if my teachers are correct?

Comment: Did your teacher copy the question from a book or did they write the question on their own? If it is the latter, it might have been a typo or something.

Comment: Also, are you asking about what should go in the blank or are you asking about the use of "for" in there?

Answer (score -1):

Your teacher  is correct. But for  and over can not come side by side.It may be  a typo.

> **My boy friend has lost twenty pounds over/for the past six months**

Here present perfect is correct the process began six months ago and has  connection to the present time. The boy friend has lost  20 pounds during the period.

Comment: The question is really about the "for" before "over" which you correctly dropped but without explanation.

Comment: "for over the past six months" is not idiomatic English - it may be a typo of "over the past 6 months". We wouldn't write "has lost 20 pounds for the past six months". It would be something like "has been on a diet for the past six months".

Comment: @ColleenV.He has been on diet is  different from losing weight.I think he has shed twenty pounds.

Comment: Yes, it is different, which is why "for" is OK in that sentence, but it's not idiomatic in "I have lost 20 lbs for the past 6 months". "I have lost 4 lbs each month for the past 5 months." would be OK.

Comment: @ColleenV.You have said that the OPs sentence was not idiomatic but now you are saying that it is idiomatic.I hope you answer and end the confusion